# How do I configure DPMS in Pop OS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, pop-os, dpms

I can't seem to get my DPMS settings working. I want to have my screen shutoff after 6 mins. Below, I have created a file:

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-dpms.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-A-0"
    Option "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags" 
    Option "StandbyTime" "300" 
    Option "SuspendTime" "330" 
    Option "OffTime" "360" 
    Option "BlankTime" "270" 
EndSection
```

However, when I run xset q after rebooting, the settings are still all zero:

```
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

I am trying to follow this example which should work: [Arch Linux Wiki - Display Power Management Signalling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Display_Power_Management_Signaling)

Any ideas?